# Pronouns grammar

Tags: pronouns

In the following sentence:

> I loved **his visits** and found myself thinking of him a lot when he was away.

I don't understand that why use "**his visits**", why not use "**his visit**"?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be related to any pronoun!! Will you please clarify?

Comment: It *could* be *his* ***visit***. But only If he only visited once. How many times did he visit? If it's talking about repeated visits (two or more), then it has to be ***visits***. There's nothing ungrammatical about the sentence. Assuming it wasn't a typo, then he's visited more than one.

Comment: Hi Jason, Many thanks for your explain, I think I get it.

Comment: Hi Virolino, sorry, it should be Possessive.